# How to change the text of a QLineEdit when the user click on the QLineEdit in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QLineEdit` with the text *"Search contents..."*.

1. I would like when `QLineEdit` has the focus or when the cursor go inside the text that the text is set to an empty string. [This works: I have no problem, I used the `cursorPositionChanged` signal of `QLineEdit`].
2. I would like also when the `QLineEdit` leaves the focus and if the text is empty that the text of the `QLineEdit` is set to *"Search contents..."*. [I don't know how to do that].

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`placeholderText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) property of `QLineEdit` is exactly what you need.